# Certificate error with EPEL repository on CentOS6.7 using mirrors.fedoraproject.org

Tags: centos, yum, epel

Can't update a CentOS 6.7 system with the EPEL repository configured.

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
failovermethod=priority
```

I get a certificate error connecting to mirrors.fedoraproject.org.  I ran the yum command with url grabber enabled and I see my system lacks the CA to validate the cert from mirrors.fedoraproject.org.

```
$ URLGRABBER_DEBUG=1 yum check-update
2015-12-17 14:05:00,510 attempt 1/10: https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64
INFO:urlgrabber:attempt 1/10: https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64
* About to connect() to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 140.211.169.206... * connected
* Connected to mirrors.fedoraproject.org (140.211.169.206) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Peer's certificate issuer is not recognized: 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US'
* NSS error -8179
* Closing connection #0
* Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
2015-12-17 14:05:00,767 exception: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
INFO:urlgrabber:exception: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
2015-12-17 14:05:00,774 retrycode (14) not in list [-1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], re-raising
INFO:urlgrabber:retrycode (14) not in list [-1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], re-raising
Could not retrieve mirrorlist https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64 error was
14: Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: epel
```

There are no updates to the ca-certificate package

```
$ yum update ca-certificates --disablerepo epel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.kernel.org
 * extras: mirror.solarvps.com
 * updates: ftp.linux.ncsu.edu
No Packages marked for Update
```

Here's the current version of the ca-certificates package

```
Name        : ca-certificates
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 2015.2.4
Release     : 65.0.1.el6_6
Size        : 3.2 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : updates
Summary     : The Mozilla CA root certificate bundle
URL         : http://www.mozilla.org/
License     : Public Domain
Description : This package contains the set of CA certificates chosen by the
            : Mozilla Foundation for use with the Internet PKI.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like iwaseantenbyagrue pointed out you can see the certificate offered with openssl s_client. The problem is that the server (mirrors.fedoraproject.org) does not offer the intermediate certificate, the

```
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
```

and you don't have the cert in your ca-bundle.

The best thing in my opinion is if the intermediate cert was added on the mirrors.fedoraproject.org, but it is not much you or I could do about this, so either you try updating the ca bundle package, or else you can download the intermediate cert yourself from [DigiCert Root Ca download page](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm). You can convert it to the x509 with openssl like this (omit -text if you want only the certificate).

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            04:e1:e7:a4:dc:5c:f2:f3:6d:c0:2b:42:b8:5d:15:9f
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 22 12:00:00 2013 GMT
            Not After : Oct 22 12:00:00 2028 GMT
        Subject: C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b6:e0:2f:c2:24:06:c8:6d:04:5f:d7:ef:0a:64:
                    06:b2:7d:22:26:65:16:ae:42:40:9b:ce:dc:9f:9f:
                    76:07:3e:c3:30:55:87:19:b9:4f:94:0e:5a:94:1f:
                    55:56:b4:c2:02:2a:af:d0:98:ee:0b:40:d7:c4:d0:
                    3b:72:c8:14:9e:ef:90:b1:11:a9:ae:d2:c8:b8:43:
                    3a:d9:0b:0b:d5:d5:95:f5:40:af:c8:1d:ed:4d:9c:
                    5f:57:b7:86:50:68:99:f5:8a:da:d2:c7:05:1f:a8:
                    97:c9:dc:a4:b1:82:84:2d:c6:ad:a5:9c:c7:19:82:
                    a6:85:0f:5e:44:58:2a:37:8f:fd:35:f1:0b:08:27:
                    32:5a:f5:bb:8b:9e:a4:bd:51:d0:27:e2:dd:3b:42:
                    33:a3:05:28:c4:bb:28:cc:9a:ac:2b:23:0d:78:c6:
                    7b:e6:5e:71:b7:4a:3e:08:fb:81:b7:16:16:a1:9d:
                    23:12:4d:e5:d7:92:08:ac:75:a4:9c:ba:cd:17:b2:
                    1e:44:35:65:7f:53:25:39:d1:1c:0a:9a:63:1b:19:
                    92:74:68:0a:37:c2:c2:52:48:cb:39:5a:a2:b6:e1:
                    5d:c1:dd:a0:20:b8:21:a2:93:26:6f:14:4a:21:41:
                    c7:ed:6d:9b:f2:48:2f:f3:03:f5:a2:68:92:53:2f:
                    5e:e3
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            Authority Information Access:
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.digicert.com

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl4.digicert.com/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crl

            X509v3 Certificate Policies:
                Policy: X509v3 Any Policy
                  CPS: https://www.digicert.com/CPS

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                51:68:FF:90:AF:02:07:75:3C:CC:D9:65:64:62:A2:12:B8:59:72:3B
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:B1:3E:C3:69:03:F8:BF:47:01:D4:98:26:1A:08:02:EF:63:64:2B:C3

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         18:8a:95:89:03:e6:6d:df:5c:fc:1d:68:ea:4a:8f:83:d6:51:
         2f:8d:6b:44:16:9e:ac:63:f5:d2:6e:6c:84:99:8b:aa:81:71:
         84:5b:ed:34:4e:b0:b7:79:92:29:cc:2d:80:6a:f0:8e:20:e1:
         79:a4:fe:03:47:13:ea:f5:86:ca:59:71:7d:f4:04:96:6b:d3:
         59:58:3d:fe:d3:31:25:5c:18:38:84:a3:e6:9f:82:fd:8c:5b:
         98:31:4e:cd:78:9e:1a:fd:85:cb:49:aa:f2:27:8b:99:72:fc:
         3e:aa:d5:41:0b:da:d5:36:a1:bf:1c:6e:47:49:7f:5e:d9:48:
         7c:03:d9:fd:8b:49:a0:98:26:42:40:eb:d6:92:11:a4:64:0a:
         57:54:c4:f5:1d:d6:02:5e:6b:ac:ee:c4:80:9a:12:72:fa:56:
         93:d7:ff:bf:30:85:06:30:bf:0b:7f:4e:ff:57:05:9d:24:ed:
         85:c3:2b:fb:a6:75:a8:ac:2d:16:ef:7d:79:27:b2:eb:c2:9d:
         0b:07:ea:aa:85:d3:01:a3:20:28:41:59:43:28:d2:81:e3:aa:
         f6:ec:7b:3b:77:b6:40:62:80:05:41:45:01:ef:17:06:3e:de:
         c0:33:9b:67:d3:61:2e:72:87:e4:69:fc:12:00:57:40:1e:70:
         f5:1e:c9:b4
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I don't remember how it is done in CentOS, but somehing like put the pem file in /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ and run `update-ca-trust` to add this cert to your truststore.

Answer (score 0):

You can double check the issue isn't with the ca-certificates by using openssl:

```
> openssl s_client -connect 140.211.169.206:443 -servername mirrors.fedoraproject.org
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = North Carolina, L = Raleigh, O = Red Hat Inc., CN = *.fedoraproject.org
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=North Carolina/L=Raleigh/O=Red Hat Inc./CN=*.fedoraproject.org
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
```

If that also fails, I would suggest you run `sudo update-ca-trust`.

Also worth checking is where your ca-bundle actually comes from:

`sudo rpm -q --whatprovides /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

It *should* be from the ca-certificates package, but if not, you may want to try re-installing it.